# fileinputstream is not reading

Tags: android, fileinputstream

I have already tried many versions published here but none worked, so I ask by myself. In my code I have this public function. The file exists and has a text, but the function doesn't return anything back.

What have I done wrong and what do I have to change and how?

```
public String lesen(String dateiname) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream fin = openFileInput(dateiname); // z.b.  "Montag.txt"
        int size;
        String neuText = null;
        while ((size = fin.read()) != -1) {
            neuText += Character.toString((char) size);
        }
        return neuText;
    }
```

Comment: "The file exists" -- how do you know? `openFileInput()` opens files in [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/13/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), which is not visible to ordinary users. Did you use `openFileOutput()` to create this file? Also, reading a file one character at a time is *very* slow, and there are better Java solutions for reading in text from an `InputStream`.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
public String readAllLinesFrom(String file) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder lines = new StringBuilder();
        try(BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
            String row = null;
            while ((row = input.readLine()) != null) {
                lines.append(row);
            }
        }
        return lines.toString();
}
```